# change class on the basis of URL using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working in wordpress, I am using jquery to add remove class in body tag.

I want to apply class "home" to homepage and for other pages I want to apply "innerpage" class to body tag.

following is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
//alert(loc);   
if (loc == "http://n.net/") 
    {
        $('body').removeClass('innerpage').addClass('home');
        $('.widget-area').removeAttr('style');

    }else {
        $('body').removeClass('home').addClass('innerpage');
        }


});
```

but it is not working if the url comes like: http://n.net/?=s

Comment: Try `loc.indexOf('"http://n.net/"') == 0`

Comment: I think still u have not get my query.
e.g stage 1: suppose if I have my page URL is http://n.net then the home page css gets apply to body.
stage 2: Suppose if my URL is http://n.net/innepage, then innerpage css gets apply
stage 3: but if my URL is http://n.net/?s= at this time home page css shld get apply which is not happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match the path, use `pathname` instead:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if(path === "/") {
  // Homepage
  $('body').removeClass('innerpage').addClass('home');
  $('.widget-area').removeAttr('style');
}
else {
  // Other pages
  $('body').removeClass('home').addClass('innerpage');
}
```

This will match for:

> http://n.net/
>
> http://n.net
>
> http://n.net/?a=1
>
> http://n.net/?a=1#hash

Have a look at all the properties of the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) object, it contains a lot more than just `href`

Comment: I do it myself.  Sometimes questions seem so clear and then you realise it actually means something completely different!

Comment: @Archer : really sorry, but that the issue I am facing. I have mention 3 stages. I have issue where 3rd stage comes in. I dont want to make it hardcoded. URL name can be anything.

Comment: @RGraham: I tried it, it works only for innerpage not for Home page, because for homepage there is not "/" at the end of URL

Comment: @RGraham: Thanks alot, it was my mistake. I paste ur code again. Its working as per expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the URL, without the querystring, use this...

```
window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
//alert(loc);   
if (loc.split('.net')[1] == '/' || loc.split('.net')[1] == '') 
{
    $('body').removeClass('innerpage').addClass('home');
    $('.widget-area').removeAttr('style');

}else {
    $('body').removeClass('home').addClass('innerpage');
    }


});
```

Comment: Its working only for innerpage, not for home page and any other page

Comment: sorry i edited it.. there is change in the split function... try now